# How to debug OFBiz in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: debugging, intellij-idea, ofbiz

I have try to debug OFBiz in IntelliJ IDEA. But I couldn't find any particular document for that. So first I try to configure debugging OFBiz in Eclipse and then try to debug OFBiz in IntelliJ with same configuration. It's working with Eclipse but it did not work with IntelliJ.

**What I have Done:**
Run > Edit Configuration

Then select Application

**Configuration option:**

**Main class:** org.ofbiz.base.start.Start

**VM option:** -Xms128M -Xmx512M

**Working directory:** (path of the OFBiz project)

**Use classpath of module:** Project directory (i.e ofbiz)

What should be the right configuration for debugging OFBiz in IntelliJ. If anyone can provide a link(where this is documented) then it also will be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run/Debug Configurations -> Add New Configuration -> Jar Application -> Then you should set Path to ofbiz.jar and working directory

For me it works good